# ActionScript 3 - Define and construct a class from a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, actionscript

I'm trying to easily add in some dynamic attributes to a few variables that I construct at the beginning of my movie clip.

The variable is called with the line:

```
var clipToUse:CustomClip = new CustomClip();
```

I need to replace the CustomClip class (which is created in the library) with a variable that's changes earlier in the function. I tried setting a variable and then using the root[variable] command, which threw an error saying that a semicolon was expected on the right bracket.

I'm at my wit's end trying to get this custom class to be defined by a variable.

Comment: What you're looking for is [getDefinitionByName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
 var ClassName:Class = getDefinitionByName('CustomClip') as Class;

 //DisplayObject/DisplayObjectContainer/Sprite/MovieClip, the base class you are using in your CustomClip
 var clipToUse:DisplayObject = new ClassName();

 addChild(clipToUse);
```